# How to override `base.html` Django admin only for one admin form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model that will be used for getting data from user.
There will be only one input field and one button for submitting.
Therefor i want to remove other buttons.

Comment: 0


I have a model that will be used for getting data from user. There will be only one input field and one button for submitting. Therefor i want to remove other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a model as `class Post(models.Model):`

In your admin.py file create something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = ...
    

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        if object_id:
            extra_context.update(
                instance=Posts.objects.get(pk=object_id)
            )
        return super().change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context
        )
```

So that whenever you go to your Posts page in the admin you will get the variable `{{instance}}`

Then you should create a new folder inside your `templates` folder and call it `admin`
then inside `admin` folder create a new file called `change_form.html` (names are important)
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template)
inside that file:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}
{% if instance %}
   PUT YOUR CHANGES IN HERE
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This will override only Post page in the admin. Other pages will stay the same.
To decide exactly where to put your changes, you can check the default `change_form.html` of django.